# How to filter which rows to select based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in the following format:

```
Name, Date, Quantity
Bike, 20 Sep 22, 1
Car, 04 Nov 22,2
Milk, 04 Nov 22, 4
```

Comma representing a column, this is stored in TestData as Sheet1.

I have the following code that successfully copies this data into another workbook as a new worksheet.

How do I filter what I copy into this sheet to just be the rows with today's date,

So instead of copying

```
Name, Date, Quantity
Bike, 20 Sep 22, 1
Car, 04 Nov 22,2
Milk, 04 Nov 22, 4
```

I copy

```
Name, Date, Quantity
Car, 04 Nov 22,2
Milk, 04 Nov 22, 4
```

My code for the copying between workbook:

```
Sub Copy_single()
    Set workbookA = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim otherWorkbook As Workbook
    folder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", 1, "Select file")
    Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=folder)
    workbookA.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=otherWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the date a date (formatted as `dd mmm yy`) or a string?

Comment: As a string but if there are ways to convert and that helps to get to a solution, that's great

Answer (score 0):

### Export Filtered By Date

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySingleToday()

    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Select the file to be opened, the destination file.
    Dim dFilePath As Variant: dFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        "Excel (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", 1, "Select file")
    If VarType(dFilePath) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub ' dialog canceled
    
    ' Open and reference the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=dFilePath)
    
    ' Reference the destination 'after' worksheet.
    Dim dwsAfter As Worksheet: Set dwsAfter = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Copy the source worksheet.
    sws.Copy Before:=dwsAfter
    
    ' Reference the just copied worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwsAfter.Previous
    
    ' Check filter status.
    Dim WasAutoFiltered As Boolean
    If dws.FilterMode Then
        If dws.AutoFilterMode Then WasAutoFiltered = True
        dws.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    ' Reference the destination ranges (with and without headers).
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim ddrg As Range: Set ddrg = drg.Resize(drg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Build the criteria string.
    Dim CriteriaString As String
    CriteriaString = "<>" & Format(Date, "dd mmm yy")
    ' If your locale is not English (but you use English months),
    ' use this workaround (note the trailing '"*"'):
    'CriteriaString = "<>" & Application.Text(Date, "dd mmm yy") & "*"
    
    ' Apply AutoFilter.
    drg.AutoFilter 2, CriteriaString
    
    ' Attempt to reference the destination visible data range (filtered rows).
    Dim dvdrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dvdrg = ddrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Clear the filter.
    If WasAutoFiltered Then
        dws.ShowAllData
    Else
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Delete the destination visible data range.
    If Not dvdrg Is Nothing Then dvdrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Save
    ' Or:
    ' Save and close the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Today's data exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```